# Calendar integration with IBM Verse

Tags: add-in, ibm-verse

I have created add-ins for Outlook and Notes and I am curious if similar functionality exists for IBM Verse.  Ideally I would be able to interact with the Verse calendar.  I've seen a Chrome extension [Chorus](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/chorus-for-ibm-verse/bnbaljnenddkjfkifdlkjjobccebnone), but that is it.

Has anyone had any experience with it or know where I could possibly could find information on it?